# Ошибка сегментирования в приложении с OpenGL, glew и glfw

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
//#include <glm/glm.cpp>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Hello, world!", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    do{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    }
    while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&      glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
}
```

Я компилировал такой командой,

```
g++ opengl.cpp -o opengl -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglfw
```

Может неправильная команда?

Comment: скомпилировал, запустил. Ничего не падает, просто черный экран. esc отпработал.

Comment: есть подозрение, что Ваша видеокарта+ОС не поддерживают OpenGL версии 3.3
Смотрите вывод `glxinfo  | grep -i "vers"`

Comment: Хм, скорее всего так, спасибо за ответ. Решил проблему понижением версии до 2.1 и удалением 2-х последующих строчек (которые идут после строк с указанием версии).

Comment: @Gleb По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была с железом: видеокарта не поддерживает OpenGL версии 3.3